# de Finetti probabilities and the repeatability of events

Tags: probability-theory

Subjective probabilities as defined by de Finetti (Theory of Probability, Volume 1 and 2) are supposed to provide a theoretical foundation for working with probabilities of non-repeatable events.

These subjective probabilities are defined as the fraction of the valuation the subjective observer assigns to an event when compared to the valuation if it would be sure to happen. This is done through a pricing function $P$, which is supposed to be coherent, for example it has to be linear: $aP(E) = P(aE)$.

Then, the probability (or "prevision") $P(X)$ is defined as being a special case of the pricing function: $P(X) = \frac{1}{a}P(aX)$ (Theory of Probability, Volume 1, Reprint from August 1995, pages 72ff.).

The definition seem intuitive to me for events which are scalable. For example, when $E$ is a production process which can be repeated many times and which yields a valuable outcome $F$ with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$, then obviously $P(E) = \frac{1}{2}P(F)$ and $P(aE) = \frac{1}{2}P(aF)$ for any scaling factor $a$.

But I don't seem to understand how to reasonably apply this to actual events that don't make sense when they are repeated. For example, with $E$ being the event that a certain (probably expensive) research leads to a breakthrough that is expected to lead to one million British Pound of net gain on the market, the valuation of $E$ is $1.000.000$ GBP. But $2E$ would not have twice that valuation because the breakthrough can only be monetized once.

So, how to properly interpret these valuations with de Finetti's subjective probabilities?

Comment: What does $aE$ mean?

Comment: @joriki: I explained this in more detail now. $aE$ is the event $E$ scaled by the factor $a$, which may either be a real number or coefficient in some dimension, like $\frac{GBP}{kg}$, in order to deal with monetary gains since these are intuitive in this context.

Comment: It doesn't become clearer just because you insert "obviously" :-). If anything, it's become less clear to me. $P(E)=\frac12P(F)$, that is, the probability of a production process is half the probability of a valuable outcome? What's the probability of a production process? What's a production process scaled by a factor? Perhaps all of this is defined in the book you're referring to, but we don't have that book (I couldn't find it online), so unfortunately you're going to have to go to the trouble of defining it for us if you want us to be able to think about and perhaps answer your question.